# What does it mean to say the smallest σ-algebra?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

I am just starting out on measure theory. What does it mean to say the smallest σ-algebra?

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra must be closed under complement, union of countably many sets, and intersection of countably many sets. Take the sets you're starting out with (some $S_i\subset X$ for $i\in I$ an index set), and do all those operations on them until you stabilise.

You could also take the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing your sets $S_i$.

Comment: Normally we say $A$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra if $A \subset B$ for every $\sigma$-algebra $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose ${\cal S}$ is a collection of sets.

We can form a $\sigma$-algebra by
taking $X = \cup_{A \in {\cal S}} A$, and letting ${\cal F} = \{ A | A \subset X \}$ which is trivially a $\sigma$-algebra. Hence there exists a $\sigma$-algebra containing the collection ${\cal S}$.

Now let ${\cal C}_{\cal S} = \{ {\cal F} | {\cal F} \text{ is a } \sigma \text{-algebra, } {\cal S} \subset {\cal F}\} $.
From the previous remark, we see that ${\cal C}_{\cal S}$ is non-empty.

Let $\sigma({\cal S}) = \cap_{{\cal F} \in {\cal C_{\cal S}}} {\cal F}$. 
It is not
hard to show that $\sigma({\cal S})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and we have
${\cal S} \subset \sigma({\cal S})$.

The collection $\sigma({\cal S})$ is called the smallest $\sigma$-algebra
containing ${\cal S}$, because if ${\cal S} \subset {\cal F}$ and
${\cal F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we must have ${\cal F} \in {\cal C}_{\cal S}$, and so $\sigma({\cal S}) \subset {\cal F}$.

Comment: Is ${\cal F}$ a family of set ${\cal A}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ${\cal A}$. Also, what ${\cal F}$ are you referring to? (I am using the symbol ${\cal F}$ in different contexts much as the symbol $x$ is used in much of mathematics).

Comment: Sorry, i mean does this statement ${\cal F} = \{ A | A \subset X \}$ imply $\cal F$ is a family of A?

Comment: It means that ${\cal F}$ consists of all subsets of $X$. Another notation is $2^X$ or ${\cal P}(X)$.

Comment: Glad to be able to help.